# how to create an generic function that its parameter allowed only String and Number in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

I want to create a generic summary method that using with numbers, char and String

```
    fun <T> sumAndPrint(vararg elements: T?): T where T : Char?, T : String?, T : Number? {
        when (elements[0]) {
            is String, is Char -> {
                var result: String = ""
                elements.forEach { result += it.toString() }
                return result as T
            }

            is Number -> {
                var result: Double = 0.0
                elements.forEach { result += it.toDouble() }
                return when(elements[0]){
                    is Float, is Double -> result as T
                    is Int -> result.toInt() as T
                    is Byte -> result.toInt().toByte() as T
                    else -> result as T
                }
            }

            else -> {
                println("Unsupported type")
                return null
            }
        }
    }
```

But I faced several error such a "Only one of the upper bounds can be a class"

I tried diffrent methods but I didnt find a solution
I'm just wondering if something like this is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible, similar to how extending multiple classes isn't possible.

However, you can make this method private, remove the `where` part, and create three non-generic public methods. These methods should accept `String`, `Char`, and `Number` elements, respectively. In the bodies of these methods, call your private function.

e.g.:

```
fun sumAndPrint(vararg elements: String): String {
    return sumAndPrint<String>(*elements)
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer! At least I've learnt that limit of generic functions